# Get-Service in .vbs file and Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm completely new at VBS scripts, however I prepared one to monitor Dynamics AOS service.

```bsh
while ((Get-Service -name "AOS60*").status -eq "Running")
{Start-Sleep -s 30}
Send-MailMessage -From AOSmonitor@abc.com -To hub.pia@abc.com -Body "AOS    Stopped" -Subject "AOS3 stopped" -SmtpServer 89.216.216.116
```

It works fine when I paste it into PowerShell and I get an email, but when I save it into file `aos.vbs` and try to run it.

```
PS C:\> cscript aosMon.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\aosMon.vbs(1, 9) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Similar way when I try to run this script in Task Scheduler (basic task, one time) it stays in Running and no email sent.

[image]

Comment: vbs and powershell are not the same thing, you have a powershell script here, hence why it works with powershell and not with `cscript`.

Comment: Just a quick question.
Any reason you want to run the Powershell script from VB and not just run the [Powershell script directly as a task](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script/)?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 OP says: `It works fine when I paste it into Powershell and I get an email, but when I save it into file aos.vbs and try to run it`. Please read the question carefully

Comment: @arco444 Bah, good catch.  That's quite obvious when phrased that way

Comment: There is a better method to accomplish what you are doing. Checking every 30 sec to see if a service is still running is silly. Look for `EventId=7036` and setup a trigger in Task Scheduler to monitor for it. You can use a custom task scheduler query like this `<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="System"><Select Path="System">*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=7036)]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='param1'] and (Data='Microsoft Dynamics AX Object Server 6.3$01-Your_AOS_ServiceName')]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='param2'] and (Data='running' or Data='stopped')]]</Select></Query></QueryList>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell file extension is `.ps1` and should be saved with the encoding `UTF8-bom`.  `vbs` is short for visual basic script, which is *not* in any way synonymous with PowerShell.  You should be able to save your contents into a `filename.ps1` file and run it from the scheduler directly.

***`filename.ps1`***

```
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
} while ((Get-Service -Name 'AOS60*').Status -eq 'Running')

$mailArgs = @{
    From       = 'AOSmonitor@abc.com'
    To         = 'hub.pia@abc.com'
    Subject    = 'AOS3 stopped'
    Body       = 'AOS Stopped'
    SmtpServer = '89.216.216.116'
}
Send-MailMessage @mailArgs
```

From here, you can set up the scheduled task.  In `Action`:

*`Program/script:`*

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

*`Add arguments (optional):`*

```
-NoProfile -NonInteractive -File "PATH\TO\filename.ps1"
```

---

Footnote: if you run into issue with execution policies, you can add

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

to the arguments (before `-File`) to get around that.